# Adding Leaflet to a Mediawiki-Page

Tags: javascript, leaflet, mediawiki

so I made a map using leaflet and want to add it into a Wikipage on my Mediawiki. Via the "MediaWiki:Common.js"-File I can load the HTML of my map into the page, as explained [here](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Adding_javascript_to_wiki_pages). 
But Leaflet requires me to add there css-File and there Javascript in the header like so:

```
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.5.1/dist/leaflet.css"
   integrity="sha512-xwE/Az9zrjBIphAcBb3F6JVqxf46+CDLwfLMHloNu6KEQCAWi6HcDUbeOfBIptF7tcCzusKFjFw2yuvEpDL9wQ=="
   crossorigin=""/>
 <!-- Make sure you put this AFTER Leaflet's CSS -->
 <script src="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.5.1/dist/leaflet.js"
   integrity="sha512-GffPMF3RvMeYyc1LWMHtK8EbPv0iNZ8/oTtHPx9/cc2ILxQ+u905qIwdpULaqDkyBKgOaB57QTMg7ztg8Jm2Og=="
   crossorigin=""></script>
```

Is there a way to load them through the Common.js?

Comment: Is there a reason you aren't using the Maps extension for your map?

Comment: Well as I understand it the Map Extension does not allow me to imput my own map. And since my Map is not of anywhere on our Planet, the Extension does not help me. Or am I wrong there?

Comment: I'm not sure. I'm trying the same thing right now, teaching it to read my own WMS server.